# Where to find "xUnit Test Project (.NET Core)"?

Tags: .net-core

I'm trying to load this template but could find it neither under the installed nor online. It supposed to be under **Installed** => **.Net Core** => **xUnit Test Project (.NET Core)**

But mine is:

**Installed** => **ASP.NET CORE**

**Online** => **Visual C#** => **ASP.NET**

There is no trace of *xUnit Test Project (.NET Core)*. Where should I find it?

Comment: Maybe there sin't one - just create a class libreary (Core) and add the xUnit package.

Comment: But in my example, it should be under the normal project class, not necessarily   class library

Comment: But it will be (has to be) a class library. If there is a template then it doesn't add much. But you don't need one.

Comment: You can create from the command line, http://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dotnet-core#create-project